# Почему Pyinstaller не компилирует python скрипт в котором есть библиотека Pynput?

Tags: python

Почему Pyinstaller не компилирует python скрипт в котором есть библиотека Pynput? В скрипте у меня так же есть и другие модули но при компиляций мне выдает ошибки связанные именно с Pynput. Вот сами ошибки :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module
File "pynput\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module
File "pynput\keyboard\__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
File "pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 76, in backend
ImportError
```

Для меня из этого мало что понятно. Буду рад любой помощи.

Comment: Есть ли какая либо дополнительная информация?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно проблема в функции input(''). Её необходимо использовать с присвоением, то есть: test = input('').

Может импорт неправильный, надо что-то типа такого:
from pynput.keyboard import Controller
или в случае, если используете import pynput, то надо писать что-то похожее: pynput.keyboard.press('A')

Можете также попробовать понизить версию пакета pip install pynput==1.6.8

Должно помочь:)